# Walk by walls in a room

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, decision-problem

## Challenge

You just entered a room. Here's how it looks (you are the X):

```
|\  /|
| \/ |
| X  |
|    |
|----|
```

You challenge yourself to see if you can reach where you started by following the walls. You go right until you find a wall. Then, you turn clockwise until you are facing parallel to the wall.

For example, if you hit a `\` while going down, you will go up-left.

After that, you continue and repeat. In this visualisation, you will leave a trail. Here is how the example above would progress:

```
|\  /|
| \/ |
| Sxx|
|   X|
|----|
```

You continue following this pattern.

```
|\  /|
|X\/ |
|xSxx|
|xxxx|
|----|
```

And yes, you reached the starting point.

```
|\  /|
|x\/ |
|xXxx|
|xxxx|
|----|
```

However, if there was a hole, you could get lost:

```
|\  /|
| \/ |
| SxxX
|    |
|----|
```

### Input

As input, in any reasonable format, your program must recieve the room you are in, which consists of walls (|/-), spaces and your starting point (the X) (the starting direction is always right).

### Output

As output, your program needs to output a truthy or falsy value representing if you got to your starting point.

## Test cases

The format here is input -> output (reason for being false).

```
/-\
|X| -> true
\-/
```

```
X -> false (hits boundary)
```

```
X    |

       -> true


    \
```

```
X    |
 -
   |   -> false (trapped in endless loop)
|
  - -
```

## Scoring

This is code-golf, so the program with the least bytes wins!

Comment: Do I understand right that the slope of the wall doesn't matter?

Comment: Can you clarify test case 3?  I don't understand why he doesn't walk forever after hitting the `\ ` and turning right.

Comment: @xnor "Do I understand right that the slope of the wall doesn't matter?"  I am also confused by this, but if it made no difference, wouldn't you bounce back and forth forever against the left well in the worked example, and never return to your `S`?  I think the path must follow the wall direction, and this would answer my question above re: test case 3, since a left diagonal path will take you home.

Comment: @Joao-3, can you clarify how the path will change when hitting a `/` from each direction.  Ie, N becomes ?,  E becomes ?, etc?  And same question for `\ `.

Comment: @Jonah the X bounces off the vertical line and heads down to the backslash. Then, it turns clockwise (Quote: *Then you follow the next appropriate direction in a clockwise cycle*) until it faces parallel to the slash (meaning it points diagonally up). Then, it treads diagonally to its original position. If you had read that quote, it would be totally clear. No need for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Edit to above comment: I made a suggested edit to clarify this anyway.

Comment: @Jonah I don't think that's truthy because when you hit the `/` you turn clockwise which takes you away from the `X`.

Comment: @Neil You are correct -- [this is a correct truthy case for recross your path without a loop](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/XwEI9LkUwABE6erqKkC5QFDDpRABpqGyNQiFIKVgdg1cNYINMoTr/38A)

Comment: I'm confused regarding test case 1, where X is blocked forever at the beginning position. Currently the rules say that when you encounter a wall, we "turn". But by doing so we stay in the same position, which in this case is also the truthy ending position! So a test case like `X|` could also return `true` since after the first "action" we already are at the truthy ending position. But it doesn't feel right of course, because X isn't entirely stuck. So in test case 1, we have to rotate **a certain number of times** to know that we are really stuck, but why? There is no rule that explains this

Comment: Could you please either :
1) Add a specific rule that details what we should be doing in this case?
2) Forbid test cases where X begins by facing a wall directly onto its right?
3) Allow truthy AND falsy results for such test cases? (because we could arguably consider that by not leaving the beginning point, we also cannot **get back** to this point, so it could be a falsy output ?). Note : the Charcoal solution seems to fall into an infinite loop with test case 1, so it could help them as well. If you choose option 2) or 3), i'll happily participate in this challenge :)

Comment: @Fhuvi No see, if it was `X|`, it would go down and return `false`. But test case 1 is locked there, so it should just stay there.

Comment: @Joao-3 Ok, i think i understand the rule behind test case 1 now. It's a specific case of infinite loop. If we detect that we're in an infinite loop BUT that we're also on the starting point, then it's a truthy test case. Could you please write a clear rule regarding the 2 cases of infinite loops instead of putting them directly in test cases? Still, in my opinion this specific test case of "X being stuck at beginning point" adds some unnecessary complexity to the challenge and you could have avoided it by just specifying that there would be no test case where X cannot move

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 94 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⪫υ¶θＰθ…θ⌕θX≔⟦⟧η≔⁰ζＷ∧ＫＫ∧¬№η⟦ⅈⅉζ⟧∨φ⁻XＫＫ«⊞η⟦ⅈⅉζ⟧¿№ X⊟ＫＤ²✳ζ«Ｍ✳ζ≔⁰φ»≔＆⁷⁻ζ＆³⁻ζ⌕-/|⊟ＫＤ²✳ζζ»Ｔ¹¦¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDLTsMwEDzHX7HyyZZcQeHAoadShARSIBIcgtoequDUK4Kd5tGK0H57WIdAihASe1jvjDWzj8SsisStsrbdGcw0iBub19VDVaBdCykhqksjagUoJ2xalri24tah9RRfWC4VbOgnrLMKc9JUwsOoq2ZvSaZnxuVio@Aa7bN/ecylHLzmSwVmgKcKGkL9KFOSRFq/COri6ztHpq4ma6NgHnv6yadmKSnfFyJVEKKtS0FdFHxKu4B3FnSb/BJOWIAp9LYcOh1N7LVXWOikQmfFmYIBNN@OQei2Wvz4Ibtg2CX1@MACnZUaevoSqx2W2u9z8TVuo@CIPj@iu7Px0cn@v3P5S/gTHthjga9irGAsJ20bA8WeQRd/Pwtg7WibfQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a rectangular array of newline-terminated strings and outputs `X` if you reach the starting point. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the map.

```
≔⪫υ¶θＰθ…θ⌕θX
```

Write the map to the canvas and start at the `X`.

```
≔⟦⟧η
```

Prepare to detect an infinite loop.

```
≔⁰ζ
```

Start moving horizontally.

```
Ｗ∧ＫＫ∧¬№η⟦ⅈⅉζ⟧∨φ⁻XＫＫ«
```

Repeat until the cursor moves out of bounds, repeats itself, or moves back on to the X.

```
⊞η⟦ⅈⅉζ⟧
```

Remember the current position for loop detection.

```
¿№ X⊟ＫＤ²✳ζ«
```

If the next step is out of bounds, empty or the start, then...

```
Ｍ✳ζ
```

... move to that square, and...

```
≔⁰φ
```

... remember that a step was taken.

```
»≔＆⁷⁻ζ＆³⁻ζ⌕-/|⊟ＫＤ²✳ζζ
```

Otherwise, rotate clockwise appropriately to the new direction.

```
»Ｔ¹¦¹
```

Output the final square.

Comment: It seems that **Test Case 1** causes your solution to get stuck in an infinite loop? [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##jVA9T8MwFJzjX/Hk6VlyVIrYOlUFJJACETAEtR2i1K0tjJ0mcRGh/e3BbqpGFQsebN@d7t5HIfOqsLnuui@ptAB8MKVrXptKmQ0yBqmrJToOik3ItK7VxuCjVSZQdGEo47D1SuJ0o0rvaTDA9PibfRdazKQtccvhXplVeGlGGRuy5ksOcoBXHFqPTq08V7jmMPXGVIgP9LWebBPYu63LdX1mQyaHmXW@qOQwzwL5Hq52yY4Hfkh0nOSPPCGRWgP2ZgoZ5ZD6jkP0rapE0Shr8JrDANpzYpTYncALxcdFwyzrgA8kEroWkORlr7yojWwwUcbVHBK7ctr2CNvTnmg82v@3EQ43rN/agbxV6hPHHMZs0nWjeEH22Z4s4hHp4p3@BQ)

Comment: @Fhuvi Whoops, despite writing my loop detection specifically with that test case in mind, I hadn't actually tested it, and it turned out two have not one but two bugs! Should be fixed now.

Comment: Well done! Your code also passes the [recross a specific space 8 times without considering it a stuck loop](https://tio.run/##jVDLTsMwEDzHX7HKyZZshcKBQ0@lCAmkQiU4FDU9VMFtLILT5tGK4H572HVaUsQFW7JnZj3jtZN0WST5MmvbfWoyDfzeburquSqMXXMhYFqXKa8lGDFko7I0a8sfcmNJCmMbCglbrEzqrDIb9FSc6NSj8WeS6XGab/hWwp2xb7SHs1CIPmu@kJD29EJCg@zYyggtU63fOd5C@DHH0LzG6FTCfEbyKy3NQuD6VPCVhImxdcnxFgmd1Q/4YoF/yR/jkAVmBcfYELwPOybvrSl0Upnc8ksJPWl@EoNJvtP8VwXjgv4tK@IHFuis1HCUb0y1N6Wm91yf2m0knMlXZ7L/tlBF7r990U/QFx7YS2E@@EDCQAzbFgCcchA5ABar2IGLgDDEOCPwWKkZHkNdAUPeDYe6J7EijOXIexB7m4tPZ2hiRTGPnFJ4qMNdEPNI0YjwXtp8gbVql30D) test case :D

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 197 <sup><s>199</s> <s>205</s> <s>208</s></sup> bytes

> Gained some bytes by improving solution, but lost some by fixing a bug regarding "bonus case 2"
> Gained 8 bytes after analyzing suggestions from *ceilingcat* !

Interesting challenge!
The input is a single string, with line breaks at the end of each row. Each row must have the same length. Returns `true` if we can reach the starting point `X`, and `false` otherwise.

```javascript
s=>{i=(d=(p,q)=>p.indexOf(q))(s,"X");l=~d(s,`
`);try{(g=(x,y)=>{d(`X `,c=s[z=i+x-y*l]||" ")+1?i=z:0;g([0,x,-y,0,-x|-y,t=x|-y][a=d(`X -|/\\`,c)],[0,y,0,x,x|y,t][a])})(1,0)}catch(e){}return"X"==s[i]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVLBbhMxEL3vV4z25CV2NwUkUCu3EhJnLhwidSPF2cymC453aztlQ1xu3PgE@Ln@SBh7W7WVKPVGGY/85s3z83xR18rVtu29MN0KD408OHm2byVbSdbzq0Ke9UetWeHwqWFXRcEcz2d5carljxXtF9miOPV2t2dryQa@I/h@xRYzWPBauovvsp0MYvdKz0PIIS8mx@et/H4yPV2ziykfuNjxKRdDoOhlDPMLJVO9CGVVEUkx54SMsIEPgWCEmBc3BTvm0@KmVr6@ZFjsbyz6rTUkTVLbdn5zUM6h9ZL51mvkrem3nuPQY@1xRSrrzrhO45Hu1iyvTGVkXJBPEn6SQ8ork08Ys@i22suGJZaioIN7pvP89vdPyE/y2z@/4v1G6CQx5pMRn2WjFpZ/HNSm1wi1cggngKbWncMVuF7VmPNsEaoKoAxZgKoqIcYZpAApCFohW2QcvN0iPGL@jM6PtMdE7Py2/grKg79ESpT10HQWr9HGJqWoqizMQlZVonyB7TWxmQ66JbHUOmmcpZJGafdMzRuqWSoS4LsHAalyvAak9XwgD15Q9ZY6tKZpTesRdNf1j9nFPRG5NjoXM0Hfv4V/6MzWPXiHrlY90qWtvxSoqKVqPFpYbjd9a9bUl671Dr4prV1yM8p94ub/OkQ/O6N39IfQ226pcaN8Wz91OLzIEz22WNvOOVA0P1i3DbGkQYL34NsNJnXRBhFopMgEElhVAUKZnIk2068cfRIi2kcn4t6zZGAmwvgiIiZ0Xt6VUZYq08COuPilQ5GlPU1rBI4J3D1O3MUpJqsikuL4QI/e@/AX)

---

This solution uses recursive calls of the `g()` function and catching exceptions to end an infinite loop (particularly useful for test cases 1 and 4)

Our position is the single int `i` corresponding to the index in our one-dimensional string. To go up or down, we substract or add the length `l` of the first row. This works only if all lines have the same length, which is a prerequisite for this code.

In each call we check the cell where we are supposed to go with our current direction (expressed with the `x` and `y` parameters of the `g()` function. These 2 parameters can only have the values `[-1, 0, 1]`) :

- if it's a `space`, we change our position to this cell and keep the same direction, then proceed to the next call
- if it's an `X` or a `line break` or if our target cell is outside of the string (`undefined`), we change our position to the index of this cell, and change our direction to `[0,0]`, then proceed to the next call. This allow to "stuck" our cursor on the target cell, and never move while we provoke an infinite loop to end the algorithm
- if we encounter a wall, we don't move but we determine the resulting direction for the next call, and we proceed with this call. For this part i created **[this tool](https://tio.run/##fZO9bsIwEMd3niK6LrFig8OIZJi60qEDQ/CAggtUKEEkoCBl7VapU7e2e1@LF0nPcQyEJB1857uf7@7vfLwujosk3G92KYvipSrWonBDmtETEeNQCGAwCdiJcjnSUY4Rp5kJBhplOdIsP5nUfI65VJTJVI7gAYpFkqh9KtxNtDukPi3dkKpsp8JULeleJYdtKtZ1HnBpd74kWkocJfFW9bfxynVNjQcghO2DwQTOX28OjOD8/e4A8bDkiJNN4yHxwDn/fDrgwRzAM9PMHsHHLwJbYNoT0qsSojwsxgFMgcL0EY1ez6XRa4ZGr@kMZBAAp8zHyLeOl1bveWmZbx03Ds/J/iZaquzpxcjF6xDZ65ln5@JLoAEWSRroIklqgHcB1lmiR0rtmr06AKuV3L6N67n8olJLus/zjjxrL2C2E2shvJOwm6J2lYOLmnLEPfDbAe8ClRq/rmZQe2Ss2e2WtOvEX8kKrU@tQNWhQfg/pLoDa6Drp9LK@JUVfw)** to help golfing it separately of the whole "mess".
- At the end we check the final position we've reached. If it's `X`, it's truthy.
- `d()` function is a shortened `indexOf` (because we use it more than 2 times)
- in the core mechanism, i used a lot of arrays combined with the already shortened `indexOf` because i throught it's the shortest way of doing a switch case?

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 484 bytes:

```py
E=enumerate
def f(b):
 r,X,Y,F=[(x,y)for x,r in E(b)for y,c in E(r)if'X'==c],0,1,0
 x,y=r.pop(0)
 while 1:
  if F==4 or(r and(x,y)==r[0][:2]):return 1
  if(len(r)>1 and(x,y,X,Y)in r)or any([(j:=x+X)<0,j>=len(b),(k:=y+Y)<0,k>=len(b[0])]):return
  B,U,I=b[j][k],X,Y
  if'|'==B:X,Y=[-1,1][Y>0],0
  if'-'==B:X,Y=0,[1,-1][X>0]
  if'\\'==B:X,Y=[1,-1][max(X,Y)>0],[1,-1][max(X,Y)>0]
  if'/'==B:X,Y=[-1,1][min(X,Y)<0],[-1,1][min(X,Y)<0]
  if(X,Y)==(U,I):r+=[(x,y,U,I)];x,y=j,k;F=0
  else:F+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHBbqMwED2vv2KUC/bGFEjSakXrHCo10l72Uq1EhNEqaYxKQgAZqg0S/56OMUmzbdaX8bz35s2MXbXNa1lMf1T6eHwSqnjbK71qFNmoFFK6ZiEBzSO@5AsR0wNvWVpqOHANWQFPyJu05S821SxLncgR4iXhPg@4T1DaCn1TlRX1GYG/r1muIEBTyFJYCDGDUlMNq2LTmwuhYz@Jw0nCQq2aN11A0Gtprgq0nwcnqZmJYVPNSlPe0phuQ3EYR@zB59u5MPo143QXina8NOBuALEBO9uj@SP/zX@KdbxN4l1ibPuGTodrPIaYitgNeJDEy7mfmI0M6Z5Jn8cBd5GOkLaklB@lltuvDtTMaxy@QrbK@9xvnxW94sEUfYHsq5hECIoL4EJj@0NmHZbcm4ff8t39QpiZVV6rcDEWwdF8bFP@WZcrvaHP@L/fhoeOv6dZ3ihNf5WF4vB8U1d51lBHFg5jCSF1AAJGoxHppATwOtKBlB6YGEEfoA8uno4YYT0ZKjxXStJFHZHS9Sw1HajIprNTak2gP/8PaNeX3Q1lBvMuVacrzvIvit62x4B2l@aDuLvwON2Rsi1vP0169u8@5Ji64Pb6SmdFQ1N6fvI6YIxdgSfX4el1eHYdvr0O3yF8fAc)

Comment: You can get it down to 446 bytes by removing the repat definitions in `\` and `/`.

Comment: [In this case](https://tio.run/##ZVHBTsJAED27X7Hh0l0ZpKseTGU4mEDixYsxKdluDMg2FMq2WUqkCf@OO1Qx0eO89@bNvJm6bVaVu3uo/ek0Qev2W@vnjWVLm/NcLGTCuIcUZjBFLQ7Qyrzy/ACeF45PAk9lCx9d6WWRR2mE@GEgBgUxC9IW/U1d1SKWjH@uitJyFUx5kfMp4j2vvPB87pZnc0SvY6OTWyMTb5u9d1ydtaK0LtiP1Y@UdpJhqJcVtbdCi3WCh34qRzGsx0j6hQSxSbDtzwjcfINhgLzYB/MneINnXOi10RtDtueB0THEeEpCiXqgQBk9G8eGEhE5uJAxaAWDQKeB7sgs@23tuO38IGhfcvgPdV3Dv/O2hTsrRtT0D@quQgWiCAFCoH73IYojzSMdfg2bxynSzrbc2WTaR3WixzbV@6Ka@6V4Df@9@j60vs6LsrFevFTOAn@92dVl0Ygoc5GUhrGd4sh7vR4bZhlnx/TIsmwwZISw2heuEbm4GO@UlPL0BQ), your code should return `none` because X would go north-east

Comment: [324 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVLBiqNAEL33VxS5aMd21WQCg27tLQFZWAJDwGDLYJKWcZJR6e5hI@t@e6ZbM3NY2LoUr96r11WlXa9f2mb52MnbbY2ieX8TstSCbNGPWEROooLKPdCYgGJzibl7ZT2tWglXJqFuYG1IC3t2nKCkdeVkDuKxSHYYsijZYJikqAj8fqkvAlJvB02rrVoaW8jYHneJscU0eWVnvHoZ6719svEwMnRdwQZxZZ6QUDYnSBFVLIV@lw1YXss@3uEfZ3Bid5vvf4QFCylzfANDts2z7xgWBnM@8m/l1U2prTE6XzAnmKp1Y6tT8W9@yF@L/FwUxl1cj6LT8FP0aylbGUsPc7NAYRYys9rVvkTxQYryfLMX0@3zoS3lyX2yhzNxnzefV/VFC@n@ahvB4Omb6i61dh3eOJQWhKgIEGazGRk4BwgGMgDnAdicwZhgTL6JgVihWtw7Ap9zMmQD4dwPJmp5p7IJPnzCyQTG@H8ydmPb6p82/1Nhh5kmstAHf9QT@zMo@3FzFTG1YGrJ1ANTq2K6RCfrRruV@3UiRSm9fQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 282 <sup><s>283</s> <s>287</s> <s>292</s></sup> bytes

> -2 and -1 bytes thanks to *ceilingcat* !
> -7 bytes with some optimizations

Not bad for Java!

The input is a single string, with line breaks at the end of each row. Each row must have the same length. Returns `true` if we can reach the starting point `X`, and `false` otherwise.

In this solution, we take advantage of the thinness of the boundary between `char` and `int` in Java.

```java
s->{int i=s.indexOf(88),l=~s.indexOf(10),x=1,y=0,z,a,c=0,d[],r=2;for(var t=s.toCharArray();r>1;y=d[z+5])x=(d=new int[]{x,-y,0,-x|-y,a=x|-y,y,0,x,x|y,a,r=(z=i+x-y*l)<0|z>=s.length()||(c=t[z])==10|c==40?0:t[i=c>31&c<41?z:i]++>0&c==88|t[i]>95?1:2})[z="-|/\\".indexOf(c)+1];return r>0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTNjts2EL7nKaY6BFIl@mezQV0r9KItckvQQ3pYwPKBpse2EpoSSHoj23JvvfXYW9uX2xfZDmnZiw2KxVKARsOZ@Wb4zVCfxZ1gnxdfHurtXJUSpBLWwkdRaji8egVQaodmKSTCB9oAWvOqUig0LONPzpR6BTbJyXD03tYJRyAfQAF/sGxyoHAoue2VeoHNr8t4NEoyxX9/3BgOkqzhw2zHB9k@E5kkuZjOMsOv8mVl4jthwBGAq35ZC/OTMWIXJ7mZDPMdX0z36dtZ0vB4wTV@9bVOZ4cmY7tskLGmJSl4EH6jyZqWNgg53vMybdjue5W8G7T7CcEr1Cu3jpO2jSV30/0s4Xw4aCXn14ObwdhNSy4nb4av5bvr4c1@XM7SdDJ4TebRqCXjbPLj25vh@OqYTPc8Ym2/KKLLEWWSDme5Qbc1GsxkkB8fck9Wx3jH2V1VLgDvhNoKh2dqXekUZtBptTBik10agE2N0uEi@aYxBu1WOeDw3dkjD3ZndoeLTfWWccBL8qMUTq7j943E2pUVASeHYEp5VOj7v/@CKMXeCt1HtFasME7SCGi70IWO8mPA/rSzDje9aut6NdXqlI4jb@d@UXw4CIUFncLS@FQJ5@cab6L7f/6AaBzd//snREl6sqcBJUq7Us9z9j/UbWhkO9qmMxBmZZPTBMMjq9H7RmxqhSCFRRgDaqkqiwuwNU14lEHUFgVAvy10C0XRh/BxCycJJ8lokSRvZ7YISf5tkt/QulOGIeWwbiu/gHDg1ugLNg5orvEOjc/XZ0VBmLcEWBSs/zLYK4LVFVRzgpMq1H0bIpdC2edD31DoXFBBrnosKAB0x4OwnpfE0csKvaZspV6WunQIqqrqJ5nYBbH1sr1kYPQ8e56fK721jxSjlaJGosS4NUNB2cWS/low325qf29oHiv4Ab4KpWwgPRzgKekvSOVpr7Ta0QuhNtVc4SbM35NGtC@F860wKE1F/1tBE4iyXPqZ9qMII7r6GwzVen5YS0PpyaF6i6KFtn/iLLSigH5HIWOeXLKxC5@BXbK0p8axoJFLvwv1aggPk9@5@ieYGfkGlTHv22lw7qD/9NfBc@i96aNr4tPpoDt7fPgP)

---

This solution transforms the input string into an array of characters, and our cursor "increases" the ASCII values of the characters it passes through.

An infinite path is detected if we pass strictly more than **8 times** through the same cell, which would return a `false`. But if this cell also happens to be our starting point `X`, then it returns a `true`.

If we aren't in an infinite loop at all, reaching the `X` or a `\n` or having an index outside of the string will return a `true` or `false` accordingly.

`r` is the result and is kind of a ternary boolean: as long as it has the value `2`, the algorithm must continue. `0` and `1` are the falsy and truthy values before normalization.

Note:

1. I reused my "wall direction conversion system", and 1-dimensional string indexing from [my JavaScript solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264729/116582).
2. For debugging purpose, we can visualize the path drawn by the cursor (via increase of the ASCII values of the characters) : to do so, move `var t=s.toCharArray()` with a `;` before the `for`, and add `System.out.println(t);` just before the `return`.